# Project has no project.properties file When creating a new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, properties-file

I just installed Eclipse on my Mac, I downloaded the bundle that provides Eclipse+SDK, I've also downloaded all the needed updates but when I create a new project I get the following error:

> [2014-08-25 16:51:02 - provaApp] Project has no project.properties
>   file! Edit the project properties to set one.

I've tried everything found here on SO but none of the answers worked, I really have no idea on how to fix this. I've also deleted and downloaded Eclipse twice.

Edit: I get also the following error if I try to edit the properties of the Project by right-clicking on Project Root folder > properties > Android 
[image]

If I try to set the project build target (in my case Android 4.4W) I can't because it doesn't save the changes.

Comment: If you're just getting started you should consider using Android Studio.  It is very stable and it seems to be getting all the love from the Android tools team.  No reason to learn Eclipse's way of doing Android only to have to migrate soon.

Answer (score 0):

What I know works is if you create a new blank project, copy that project.properties file into the existing project and it should work.  Also try running a clean project sometimes helps, but very rarely.

It's a pain but luckily this happens rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a project.properties file with this content:

```
target=android-19
```